# Dynamic paint on changing geometry

Tags: masking, vertex-weights, dynamic-paint

I want to use dynamic paint (wave) on a mesh which geometry is changing, and it seems dynamic paint doesn't support this.

The aim is to have dynamic paint a large scale object (ocean) with a small brush (like a boat), but with decent performance.

To do this I'm using the mask modifier to restrict the dynamic paint effect on only a fraction of the original mesh (with the help of weight proximity). With this method I could easily drag the brush all around the ocean, and only simulate dynamic paint locally around the brush.

Unfortunately, dynamic has no effect on the mesh as soon as I put the mask modifier before it on the stack.

Here is my modifier stack (only vertex weight proximity, mask, and dynamic paint matter):
[image: Modifier stack]

Do you have any idea of how I could reach my goal with this or another technique?

Thanks!